# Cancel/insert/update not saving to the DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I am working on Northwind database reproducing this [demo](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/edit-form-types/defaultvb.aspx). The code is not showing any error  but all operations insert/update/delete are only temporary. If I add a record or cancel or update the next time I run the code, the content of the table is still the original one without any of the modification I did saved inthe db.

```
private static DataTable GetDataTable(string queryString)
  {
      String connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NORTHWNDConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
       SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
       SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
       mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, mySqlConnection);

       DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
       mySqlConnection.Open();
       try
       {
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
       }
       finally
       {
            mySqlConnection.Close();
       }

       return myDataTable;
  }

  private DataTable Employees
  {
       get
       {
            object obj = this.Session["Employees"];
            if ((!(obj == null)))
            {
                 return ((DataTable)(obj));
            }
            DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
            myDataTable = GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM Employees");
            this.Session["Employees"] = myDataTable;
            return myDataTable;
       }
  }

  protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
  {
       this.RadGrid1.DataSource = this.Employees;
       this.Employees.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { this.Employees.Columns["EmployeeID"] };
  }

  protected void RadGrid1_UpdateCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
  {
       GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
       UserControl userControl = (UserControl)e.Item.FindControl(GridEditFormItem.EditFormUserControlID);

       //Prepare new row to add it in the DataSource
       DataRow[] changedRows = this.Employees.Select("EmployeeID = " + editedItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[editedItem.ItemIndex]["EmployeeID"]);

       if (changedRows.Length != 1)
       {
            RadGrid1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Unable to locate the Employee for updating."));
            e.Canceled = true;
            return;
       }

       //Update new values
       Hashtable newValues = new Hashtable();

       newValues["Country"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox7") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["City"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox8") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["Region"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox9") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["HomePhone"] = (userControl.FindControl("HomePhoneBox") as RadMaskedTextBox).Text;
       newValues["BirthDate"] = (userControl.FindControl("BirthDatePicker") as RadDatePicker).SelectedDate.ToString();
       newValues["TitleOfCourtesy"] = (userControl.FindControl("ddlTOC") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;

       newValues["Notes"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["Address"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox6") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["FirstName"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox2") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["LastName"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox3") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["HireDate"] = (userControl.FindControl("HireDatePicker") as RadDatePicker).SelectedDate.ToString();
       newValues["Title"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox4") as TextBox).Text;

       changedRows[0].BeginEdit();
       try
       {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in newValues)
            {
                 changedRows[0][(string)entry.Key] = entry.Value;
            }
            changedRows[0].EndEdit();
            this.Employees.AcceptChanges();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
            changedRows[0].CancelEdit();

            Label lblError = new Label();
            lblError.Text = "Unable to update Employees. Reason: " + ex.Message;
            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            RadGrid1.Controls.Add(lblError);

            e.Canceled = true;
       }
  }

  protected void RadGrid1_InsertCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
  {
       UserControl userControl = (UserControl)e.Item.FindControl(GridEditFormItem.EditFormUserControlID);

       //Create new row in the DataSource
       DataRow newRow = this.Employees.NewRow();

       //Insert new values
       Hashtable newValues = new Hashtable();

       newValues["Country"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox7") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["City"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox8") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["Region"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox9") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["HomePhone"] = (userControl.FindControl("HomePhoneBox") as RadMaskedTextBox).Text;
       newValues["BirthDate"] = (userControl.FindControl("BirthDatePicker") as RadDatePicker).SelectedDate.ToString();
       newValues["TitleOfCourtesy"] = (userControl.FindControl("ddlTOC") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;

       newValues["Notes"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["Address"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox6") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["FirstName"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox2") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["LastName"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox3") as TextBox).Text;
       newValues["HireDate"] = (userControl.FindControl("HireDatePicker") as RadDatePicker).SelectedDate.ToString();
       newValues["Title"] = (userControl.FindControl("TextBox4") as TextBox).Text;

       //make sure that unique primary key value is generated for the inserted row
       newValues["EmployeeID"] = (int)this.Employees.Rows[this.Employees.Rows.Count - 1]["EmployeeID"] + 1;
       try
       {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in newValues)
            {
                 newRow[(string)entry.Key] = entry.Value;
            }
            this.Employees.Rows.Add(newRow);
            this.Employees.AcceptChanges();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
            Label lblError = new Label();
            lblError.Text = "Unable to insert Employees. Reason: " + ex.Message;
            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            RadGrid1.Controls.Add(lblError);

            e.Canceled = true;
       }
  }
  protected void RadGrid1_DeleteCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
  {
       string iD = (e.Item as GridDataItem).OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["EmployeeID"].ToString();
       DataTable employeeTable = this.Employees;
       if (employeeTable.Rows.Find(iD) != null)
       {
            employeeTable.Rows.Find(iD).Delete();
            employeeTable.AcceptChanges();
       }
  }
```

Why my insert/delete/update are only temporary and visible in the current session? How can I fix this to get insert/update/delete changing the data in the database?

Comment: Where are you actually saving data back to the database?

Comment: @dotNET, yes, I would like to save back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledge that `Rows.Add()` or `AcceptChanges()` do NOT write anything to the underlying database. They only operate on the in-memory data structures such as DataTables and DataSets. To actually save changes, you must:

1. Either use `TableAdapter.Update()` method and supply your modified `DataTable` to it.
2. Use `SqlCommand` and manually execute `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` commands.

You must NOT call `AcceptChanges()` before sending your changes back to the database.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will try to follow your recomendation. However, being a very self learner beginner would dramaticaly help e if you can post the mods I need to make to the above code. This would support me to understand how to do it and finally learn it.

Comment: I have used typed DataSets for years for this kind of stuff and I recommend you go that path. VS and .NET can do a lot of work for you regarding these basic CRUD operations. Learn about Typed DataSets on the Internet. There are countless good resources available.

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't be here asking for help if I could do it.